# How to serialize a Guid with C# without creating an object?

Tags: c#, serialization, json.net

I want my Guids to be serialized into a short form of Guid ([as seen here](http://www.singular.co.nz/2007/12/shortguid-a-shorter-and-url-friendly-guid-in-c-sharp/)). For full compatibility, I want the ShortGuid class to serialize into the short form, and not the long form.

I've tried [using custom serialization](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty01x675(v=vs.110).aspx), but I can't seem to make the whole object serialize into the short string, only into an object which contains the string. This is what I've tried:

```
[Serializable]
public class ShortGuid : ISerializable
{
    public Guid Guid { get; }
    protected ShortGuid(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        Guid = Decode(info.GetString("Guid"));
    }

    public void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        info.AddValue("Guid", Encode(Guid));
    }
}
```

Which works, but if I serialize it:

```
var guid = new ShortGuid(Guid.NewGuid());
var str = JsonConvert.Serialize(guid);
```

The serialized string I get looks like this:

```
{ Guid: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" }
```

While the serialized string I WANT is just

```
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

I've turned everything around, but can't get this to work. How can this be done?

NOTE: I don't want this to work only on JsonConvert, this is only an example. I would like the class the always be serialized correctly.

Comment: so how about : ``var str = JsonConvert.Serialize(guid.Guid);``?

Comment: But then it would serialize in the long form, I.E. xxxxxxx-xxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxx

Comment: AFAIK that is how all objects serialize/deserialize themselves. SerializationInfo is like a Dictionary of keys and associated values. The fact that your class only has a single key does not matter for this, you still have to put it in there, just like everybody else.

Comment: Looks like you are mixing up serialization formats.  What you've written only applies to binary serialization.  It never generates strings and Guid already supports it and it is "short" as it can possibly be, 16 bytes.  What you want however appears to be JSON serialization.  Which requires "Guid", the format demands it.  So the only problem is that you don't have a problem.

Comment: ISerializable applies to all serialization formats, not just binary (from the msdn article link). The format does not require a guid to be nested. I could write valid json (or xml) that serializes guids in a more compact manner. The question is how so I tell the serialization I don't need a full dictionary of values, but a single value

Comment: "ISerializable applies to all serialization formats" where did you read that?

Comment: "Any class that might be serialized must be marked with the SerializableAttribute. If a class needs to control its serialization process, it can implement the ISerializable interface." Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.iserializable(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

this work perfectly for me:

```
public class GuidShortGuidConverter : JsonConverter
        {
            public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
            {
                return objectType == typeof(Guid);
            }

            public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
            {
                var shortGuid = new ShortGuid(reader.Value.ToString());
                return shortGuid.Guid;
            }

            public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
            {
                var customValue = new ShortGuid((Guid) value);
                writer.WriteValue(customValue.ToString());
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want is not about serialization but implicit casting.
Serialization works on structured key/value base depending on serialization type.

With implicit string casting

```
public static implicit operator string(ShortGuid shortGuid)
{
   return Encode(sh.Guid);
}
```

You can use

```
var guid = new ShortGuid(Guid.NewGuid());
string str = guid;
```

Comment: I want to be able to return a ShortGuid via a service and have it return the string representing it, and recieve it back as well. I don't understand what implicit casting has to do with it